# AFNetworking/NSURLConnection receiving NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=9 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Bad file descriptor"

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, afnetworking

In my app which uses AFNetworking/NSURLConnection for sending requests to the server I sometimes (very rarely) see this error in operation failure block:

```
Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=9 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Bad file descriptor"
```

At https://devforums.apple.com/message/278770#278770 there's an answer to a similar question:

> It means that someone has been deallocating file descriptors out from underneath NSURLConnection.

But in my own code I don't touch any streams of file descriptors in any way. It's just simple GET/POST requests.

What could be the cause of this problem?

Has someone encountered this error in their AFNetworking operations?

Also, how can I close this file descriptor deliberately if I really wanted to? The answer to this question will help me to understand the problem better.

Comment: Hi, Ive just started getting the same error with one of my clients. Did you ever get to the bottom of the problem?

Comment: No, unfortunately. I just treat them as any other network error.

Comment: I'm using `NSURLSession` on iOS 15 and I occasionally receive this error too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this Apple TechNote](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2277/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010841-CH1-SUBSECTION3) on multitasking and networking, you can get `EBADF` (POSIX error 9) if the app is suspended and the socket is reclaimed.

> Note: When your app resumes execution the actual error returned by a
>   socket's whose resources have been reclaimed is purposely not
>   specified here to allow for future refinements. However, in many cases
>   the error will be `EBADF`, which is probably not what you were
>   expecting! Under normal circumstances `EBADF` means that the app has
>   passed an invalid file descriptor to a system call. However, in the
>   case of a socket whose resources have been reclaimed, it does not mean
>   that the file descriptor was invalid, just that the socket is no
>   longer usable.

Answer (score 2):

(I don't think this is a complete answer, but I'm hoping it will be helpful and can be turned into one.)

The error you're looking at it `EBADF`. It's returned from operating with a closed file. But you've figured this out already. :)

Assuming you're not using the stdio library, I think what you're running into is the equivalent of an overrelease. Basically, you're handing off ownership of a file to something, which is then closing it.

You should be paying particular attention to `NSFileHandle`, especially to see if you or anyone is calling `initWithFileDescriptor:`, `copy`ing a file, etc. These could cause the `NSFileHandle` to take ownership of the file descriptor, which means closing it when it's deallocated.

Look less at your networking code, and more at how you're setting up the files.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! According to my code this error comes directly from NSURLConnectionDelegate connection:didFailWithError: callback. How could any of the files I open in my app cause this error?

Comment: Files act more like raw pointers than Objective-C object, if that makes any sense to you. An object can be owned many times, and each of those ownership flags needs to disappear before the object itself is released from memory. In contrast, you only need to close a file handle once for it to be closed. This is why I'm wondering if more than one object has the same file handle, and one of those file handles is being closed.